# Sass is returning a list of negative numbers instead of subtracting them

Tags: sass

I'm trying to do math operation with lengths:

```
$itemWidth: 25px;
$item2Width: 80px;

element {
    width: $itemWidth/2-$item2Width/2-5px
}
```

However, it outputs `-52.5px -5px` How to do it right?

Comment: Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927007/how-do-you-remove-units-of-measurement-from-a-sass-mixin-equation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Sass 3.2 parser seems to be confused by your lack of whitespace between the operators (it thinks you mean negative 5px rather than subtract 5px):

```
element {
    width: $itemWidth / 2 - $item2Width / 2 - 5px;
}
```

This is fixed in Sass 3.3, but you'll need to upgrade Compass to 1.0 (since 0.12 is incompatible with Sass 3.3).

Note that Sass will always treat numbers immediately preceded by a dash/hyphen as negation.  This means that `1 -2` is treated as a list of numbers containing the positive number one and the negative number two, rather than evaluating to the negative number 1.

Comment: Oh it works actually, thanks! I'll check those newer version (though I installed it both through gem so I though I would get the newest version)

Comment: Compass 0.12 is the stable version, so technically you do have the latest versions.  To get 1.0, you have to install using the --pre flag (`sudo gem install compass --pre`).

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the calculation in parentheses. This tells SASS that the whole thing is part of a calculation.

```
$itemWidth: 25px;
$item2Width: 80px;

element {
    width: ($itemWidth/2-$item2Width/2-5px);
}
```

Comment: I did `(-$itemWidth/2-$item2Width/2-5px);` but it still generates `-52.5px -5px;`

Comment: @simPod Are you sure you don't have `(-$itemWidth/2-$item2Width/2 -5px);` with a space between 2 and the minus sign?

Comment: @Paulie_D yup, pretty sure. I have this `(-$itemWidth/2-$item2Width/2-5px);`

Comment: Yes, see http://i.imgur.com/nNHA2nJ.png. What is this magic? I have compass 0.12.6

Comment: The parentheses don't do anything.  You get the same results with or without them (see: http://sassmeister.com/gist/495f1d7d587a98b150ed).