# Sass/Compass not doing math when compiling

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

Sorry for the not very descriptive question, but I'm not sure what else to say, it really has gone crazy.

On my machine I have grunt-contrib-compass installed, my package.json has this line in it...

"grunt-contrib-compass": "1.0.1",

My grunt file is running properly and is compiling my SASS, except none of the math works. When I commit to Github and my colleague compiles it, the math works, even though he has the same setup as me. Same grunt file and same npm packages installed via npm install.

To test what was working and what was not working I set up the following section in my SASS. I have commented the lines I want to work, the others are just test cases.

```
$hSpace: (20px, 24px, 30px, 30px, 40px, 60px);

.xxx{
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 10/2 * 1px;
    padding: nth($hSpace, 3)/2;   <---- This one
    padding: nth($hSpace, 3);
    padding: 30/2px;
    padding: 30/2 * 1px;
}
```

This is the output when I run grunt.

```
.xxx {
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 30px/2;     <---- Produces this
    padding: 30px;
    padding: 30/2px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

and this is what it looks like when my colleague runs grunt.

```
.xxx {
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 15px;      <---- When it should produce this
    padding: 30px;
    padding: 30/2px;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

Our setups seem identical, so I really can't understand why my compiler is not working.

Would really appreciate any ideas, even if they're just guesses.

Comment: Are you both running the same version of Sass? I have had issues previously where the version of Sass is not compatible with the version of compass. Which has thrown weird errors.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with LibSass or Sass (3.4, 3.3, or 3.2) on  http://sassmeister.com/.  Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552869/sass-do-math-operations-with-variables-containing-px

Comment: Also, you really need to figure out an appropriate title here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. And yeah, as I said I know the title isn't good but I can't even work out what the problem is related to. It's compiling with no errors but not doing the math.

Comment: @jonhobbs I can reproduce this. I am running an old version of compass though, `grunt-contrib-compass: 0.5.0`, `sass: 3.2.10` and `compass: 0.12.2` I would suggest checking your version numbers of the 3 and making sure they are the same as your colleague.

Comment: Thanks David. It was getting too confusing working out which versions to use because none of the version numbers of compass/sass/contrib-compass match. I just did a fresh gem install compass, gem install sass and npm install and it seems to work! At first I got a new error "Unable to load extension: compass-rails" so I did gem install compass-rails which still didn't work so i tried 'gem uninstall compass-rails' and that seemed to work. No errors on compilation now and math being done. If you'd like to put your comment as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @jonhobbs ah, just as i finished my answer :) ok just ignore the below. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this bug using the version numbers i stated in the comment above. Whilst I suggest you check your version numbers as I have suggested in the comments, you can solve this by changing the `/2` to `* 0.5` which to me suggests that the version of the packages your using are not the same as your colleagues and do not support / have a bug in the syntax of the dividing code.

$hSpace: (20px, 24px, 30px, 30px, 40px, 60px);

```
.xxx{
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 10/2 * 1px;
    padding: nth($hSpace, 3) / 2;
    padding: nth($hSpace, 3);
    padding: 30/2px;
    padding: 30/2 * 1px;
}
```

compiles to

```
.xxx {
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 30px/2;
    padding: 30px;
    padding: 30/2px;
    padding: 15px;

}
```

whilst

```
.xxx{
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 10/2 * 1px;
    padding: nth($hSpace, 3) * 0.5;
    padding: nth($hSpace, 3);
    padding: 30/2px;
    padding: 30/2 * 1px;
}
```

compiles to

```
.xxx {
    padding: 10px;
    padding: 10px/2;
    padding: 10/2;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding: 30px;
    padding: 30/2px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

which is what your colleague has.