# Using negative values fails the execution in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have a couple of SCSS selectors where I use the below code which works fine:

```
.order-summary{
    background-color: #e2f0f3;
    padding: $padding-large-horizontal+5;
}
```

but whenever I change to below code (as negative value) it shows error

```
.order-summary{
    background-color: #e2f0f3;
    padding: $padding-large-horizontal-1;
}
```

**$padding-large-horizontal is already defined as base 12px;**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552869/sass-do-math-operations-with-variables-containing-px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use like below

```
padding: ($padding-large-horizontal - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only due to the dash. SASS thinks that ***$padding-large-horizontal-1*** is the name of the variable. You have to separate as well:

```
$padding-large-horizontal -1
```